# what is the difference between 'pairing' and 'session' in walletConnect v2

Tags: walletconnect

I'm newby at wallet connect v2.

Currently, I'm having difficulties understanding difference between session pairing.

I'll be glab if anyone could help me understanding the difference :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A session refers to a live connection between a user's wallet and a dApp, while pairing refers to the initial process of establishing a secure connection between the wallet and the dApp.

When a user opens a dApp that supports WalletConnect, the dApp will generate a unique pairing code that the user must scan with their wallet app to initiate the pairing process. Once the pairing is complete, a session is established, which allows the dApp to communicate with the wallet app securely over the internet.

During a session, the dApp can send requests to the wallet app, such as signing transactions or messages, and the wallet app can send responses back to the dApp. The session remains active until the user closes the dApp or disconnects the wallet.

Comment: thanks for response!!! really helped me understanding a lot!!!